# Make all the strings of a string array into lower case except for the first word

Tags: php, arrays, string

Supposing I have an array `Tomat, Ost`
How can I accomplish so it is like this: `Tomat, ost`?

```
$ingredient_a = Array('Tomat', 'Ost');
echo implode(', ', $ingredient_a);
```

Comment: Have you made *any* attempt to solve *any* part of this problem?

Comment: Yes. `echo implode(', ', array_map('strtolower', $ingredient_a));` but it only makes all words lowercase.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ucfirst` and `array_map` with `strtolower`

```
echo ucfirst(implode(', ', array_map('strtolower',$ingredient_a)));
```

Comment: This does not match the problem statement; it *assumes* that the first word is already capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ingredient_a = array('Tomat', 'Ost');
$new = array();

foreach($ingredient_a as $key => $value) {
    $key == 0 ? $new[] = $value : $new[] = strtolower($value);
}

echo implode(', ', $new);
```